# How to redirect the authentified user to specific page

Tags: laravel

I'm new in laravel and I create 3 kind of user

1. sup has view called sup
2. ass has view called ass
3. emp has view called emp

In the table of user I add row called **role** allow me to distinguish every category mentionned of users.

Here is the table user:

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->char('role',3);
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

I want when each one authentified he will be  redirected to his specific view, so I thought if I can change the value of

**protected $redirectTo = '';**

dynamically i can redirect each one to his specific page : 
so I modify the construct of Login controller in this way

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        if (Auth::check()) {
            // The user is logged in...
            // Get the currently authenticated user...
            $user = Auth::user();
            $id= Auth::id();
            $userline=User::where('id',$id)->get()->last();
            if ($userline->role==='ass')
               $redirectTo ='Assistante';
       }
   }
```

and here is the routes:

```
Route::get('Assistante','AssController@index');
Auth::routes();
Route::get('', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

and here is the AssController :

```
class AssController extends Controller
{
      /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
      public function __construct()
      {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('Assistante');
    }
}
```

but it still redirect them to the same page.
and even though i use **protected $redirectTo = 'Assistante';** it still redirect me to the home page instead of Assistante page!

what should I do to solve this problem?

I found also this class in the middleware does not it that makes this problem:

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Because I add another middleware

```
class RedirectUser
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check())
        {
            $user = Auth::user();
            if($user->role === 'ass')
            {
             return redirect('/Assistante');
         }elseif ($user->role === 'sup')
         {
            return redirect('/Superieur');
        }elseif ($user->role === 'emp')
        {
            return redirect('/Employe');
        }
    }
    else{
     return redirect('/login');
 }
 return $next($request);
}
}
```

Comment: have you tried using middlewares?

Comment: just this one  $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');

Comment: do you have a route for `Assistante` ?

Comment: yes I do here it is : Route::get('Assistante','AssController@index');

Auth::routes();
Route::get('', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Comment: add a route name to the `Assistante` to use my answer  `Route::get('Assistante','AssController@index')->name('Assistante'');`

Comment: and you want the users to be redirected when they access the home?

Comment: no I want him to be redirected once he authetified according to its role

Comment: attach the middleware to the `home` route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly T reached to do it, these by modifying **LoginController** and **RedirectIfAuthenticated** .

I found that I do not need to create another middleware since **RedirectIfAuthenticated** called **guest** is already existing.

what I have done was:

I comment:

```
if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
return redirect('/home');}
```

in handle function in order to write my own logic in Login controller in the **authenticated** function.

Here is the complete solution:

users table:

```
 public function up()
      {
      Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) { 
      $table->bigInteger('id');
      $table->string('Nom',20);
      $table->string('Prenom',20);
      $table->date('DateRecrut');
      $table->string('password');
      $table->string('email',30)->unique();
      $table->char('role',3);
      $table->rememberToken();
      $table->primary('id');
      });
      }
```

The handle function in  **RedirectIfAuthenticated** middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
     {
     /*if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
     return redirect('/home');
     }*/ 
     return $next($request);
     }
```

The LoginController:

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
  {
  if (Auth::check())
  {if($user->role === 'ass')
  return redirect('/Assistante');
  elseif ($user->role === 'sup')
  return redirect('/Superieur');
  elseif ($user->role === 'emp')
  return redirect('/Employe');
  }
  else
  return redirect('/login');
  }
  /**
  * Create a new controller instance.
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function __construct()
  {
  $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
  }
```

And finally the routes:

```
Auth::routes();
 Route::get('', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
 Route::get('Assistante','AssController@index')->name('Assist‌​‌​ante');
 Route::get('Employe','EmpController@index')->name('Employe');
 Route::get('Superieur','SupController@index')->name('Superieur');
```

Answer (score 1):

Read about creating middlewares form the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware)

Create your own middleware using the `php artisan make:middleware` comand. Open the middleware folder in the app directory. Add the following to the handle method of your `middleware`

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check())
        {
            $user = Auth::user();
            if($user->role === 'ass')
            {
                return redirect()->route('Assistante');
            }elseif ($user->role === 'sup')
            {
                return redirect()->route('Sup route here');
            }elseif ($user->role === 'emp')
            {
                return redirect()->route('emp route here');
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Register your middleware in the `app\Http\Kernel.php` file and add the middleware to the route of your choice

Comment: I do but i have the same problem .

Comment: did you create and add the middleware to the kernel.php?

Comment: yes i do this : 'ruser' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectUser::class, in  protected $routeMiddleware

Comment: and `Route::get('', 'HomeController@index')->name('home')->middleware('ruser');`?

Comment: i have gotten this problem : 
(1/1) InvalidArgumentException
Route [Assistante] not defined.

Comment: did you modify the `Assistante` route to `Route::get('Assistante','AssController@index')->name('Assist‌​ante');` ?

Comment: I do what you have said right now but I get this issue:(1/1) InvalidArgumentException
Route [Assistante] not defined.

Comment: waht I have written in fact was: Route::get('Assistante','AssController@index')->name('Assist‌​‌​ante')->middleware('ruser');

Comment: inside the middleware, do `return redirect('/Assistante');`

Comment: now it redirects me directly to the Assistante page without passing by authentification but it shows: this page does not function.

Comment: you mean unauthenticated users can also access the `Assistante`?

Comment: so if the user is not authenticated, it should redirect to the login page right?

Comment: i have edited my answer ... check it out .. added an else statement to redirect unauthenticated users to `/login`

Comment: yes right if it's really the Assistante that login it redirected to the right page however the Assitante page shows that : that page does not function and localhost:has redirected you to too many times.

Comment: the complete message is : here is the complete message :This error message appears when Chrome has stopped because the page has generated too many redirect attempts.

Sometimes pages do not open because cookies do not work properly. To correct this error, try removing cookies.

Comment: lets discuss this in chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/154165/norris-oduro

Comment: You must have 20 reputation on ... I have just 1

Comment: how much reputation do you have now?

Comment: 6 :they add them because of this question I tag today. it's 1 :( I have seen badge instead of reputation

Comment: i have edited my answer again .. now add the `auth` middleware to the `home` route too

Comment: I added what I do right now check it maybe the problem is to add another middleware even though their is an existing one

Answer (score 0):

In your code where you change the `redirectTo` property you will have to access the instance variable instead of creating a local one, i.e do 
`$this->redirectTo ='Assistante';` instead of `$redirectTo ='Assistante';`

Comment: I do but it still redirect me  home page instead of Assistante page. what about if I use the redirectTo  function how can I use it ?

Comment: you need to override that function in the current controller and it should return the route to the page you want to redirect, its that simple.